# Sublime Text: Enable search highlighting for large files

Tags: search, find, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I have a file that I refer to routinely (it consists of timestamps), and I use Sublime Text to edit it. Normally, when I search for a token in Sublime (Command-F), all instances of the token are also highlighted.

[image]

However, the file recently went above 30,000 lines, and this seems to be a threshold for Sublime to automatically disable search highlighting.

[image]

Is there a way to re-enable search highlighting in Sublime?

Comment: You can *try* setting `"find_in_files_max_result_size": 0,`, but I don't know if it affects this particular feature.

Comment: Thanks MattDMo! I updated my `sublime-settings` preferences to include that option, but looks like that didn't work

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find anything else in the settings. I think it's a built-in thing to keep Sublime from bogging down. I know that after a certain line length syntax highlighting stops working, so for example when you're looking at minified JS files there's no color.

Comment: It's already stated before that the highlight matches is disabled for large files to keep the UI from being locked. I guess the only thing to do would be to open an issue on https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues to make the limits configurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been [recently resolved](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/4591#issuecomment-912209022).

> Build 4114 adds the following options in the Sublime Preferences to make these kind of options configurable
>
> - `find_scroll_highlights_limit`
> - `find_highlight_matches_max_size`
> - `find_regex_highlight_matches_max_size`
> - `find_in_files_max_result_size`